# PHP - Should I create an artificial inheritance in DAO classes when I don't need them?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, pdo

All,

Building a small web app using PHP.  I don't have much programming experience.

In my app, I have created a class to access DB records which I call `DAO_DBrecords`.  The class includes basic functions to create new records, update existing records, etc.  Currently, the class satisfies all my DAO needs for all my DB tables.  In the functions, I pass as one of the argument a string that represents the DB table (`users`, `articles`, etc).

At this point I could do either of 3 things:

1. Use this class throughout my program whatever the type of record (i.e., table) I'm dealing with.
2. Create specific classes for each type of record (e.g., `DAO_Users`), which inherit from `DAO_DBrecords` but are otherwise empty.
3. Create specific classes for each type of record (e.g., `DAO_Users`),  which inherit from `DAO_DBrecords` and specify the DB table the class can access via a variable (e.g., `private $table = 'users'`).  In the parent class, the variable would be null, or an empty string.

Again, at this point I am not envisioning the need for table specific functions (but that might change).

Which of those (if any) is the right approach?

Thanks,

JDelage

Edit:  I have edited option 3 which previously read:
3. Create specific classes for each type of record (e.g., `DAO_Users`),  which inherit from `DAO_DBrecords` and specify the DB table the class can access via a constant (e.g., `const TABLE = 'users'`).  In the parent class, the constant would be null, or an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will choose the 3rd option. In `DAO_Users` you can eventually put methods to do specific things on the user record itself (for example, create and store a salted password, send verification email, fetch all user's friends from the database as `DAO_Users` collection, fetch all user's comments, etc).

In this way you can both use a DAO pattern and organize all app "actions" in classes by action target.